# Dependencies installation in Google Cloud pre-build container

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to use a pre-build container in Google Cloud VERTEX AI for my python script. According to the documentation I need to create requirements.txt and then VERTEX AI will install these additional dependencies inside the container. The problem that for the bunch of dependencies I have error like this: "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement dvc-data==0.47.5 (from aiplatform-custom-trainer-script) (from versions: 0.0.1, 0.0.2)". Or this one: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jupyter-core==5.1.2 (from aiplatform-custom-trainer-script) (from versions: 4.0.0, 4.0.1, 4.0.2, 4.0.3, 4.0.4, 4.0.5, 4.0.6, 4.1.0, 4.1.1, 4.2.0, 4.2.1, 4.3.0, 4.4.0, 4.5.0, 4.6.0, 4.6.1, 4.6.2, 4.6.3, 4.7.0rc0, 4.7.0, 4.7.1, 4.8.0b0, 4.8.0rc0, 4.8.0rc1, 4.8.0, 4.8.1, 4.8.2, 4.9.0rc0, 4.9.0, 4.9.1rc0, 4.9.1, 4.9.2, 4.10.0, 4.11.0, 4.11.1, 4.11.2, 4.12.0, 5.0.0rc0, 5.0.0rc1, 5.0.0rc2)

For me it sound like a pre-built container could not call a pypi and install required version of dependencies. And it happens not only for the dvc-data==0.47.5, but for a big amount of dependencies from requirements.txt.
Here is my code:

```
requirements = subprocess.check_output(
    ["poetry", "export", "-f", "requirements.txt", "--without-hashes"],
)
requirements = [ line.decode().split("; ")[0] for line in requirements.splitlines() ]

aiplatform.init(project=GCP_PROJECT_ID, location="europe-west3")
job = DependencyCustomTrainingJob(
    display_name="supi-trainer",
    script_path="gcp_train_script.py",
    container_uri="europe-docker.pkg.dev/vertex-ai/training/tf-cpu.2-9:latest",
    staging_bucket="gs://data-798-supi-in-vertexai",
    requirements=requirements,
    dependencies=[
        "dcb_supervised_classifier_trainer",
        "config",
        ".dvc/config",
        "data.dvc",
        "poetry.lock",
        "pyproject.toml"
    ],
)
job.run()
```

1. Tried to use requirements.txt without exact versions.
2. Now instead of requirements txt and further installation through the pip install requirements.txt I try to use poetry install. But I did not manage it yet. And I am not sure is it possible to do (poetry inside the pre-build container in GC VERTEX AI)